# I want to print prime number

Tags: python-3.6

I want to print prime number, but in my code print() showing invalid syntax.My question is about, I can not understand why it is showing. So please help me what should be modify needed in the code and please tell me code is wright or wrong.

```
 def isPrime(num):
     for i in range(2,num):
         if num % i == 0 and num % 1 == 0:
             return True
         else:
             return False
     else:
         return None
 num = int(input("Enter a number:")
 print(isPrime(num))
```

Comment: Can you also post the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

`num = int(input("Enter a number:")`

You missed a parentheses. It should be:

`num = int(input("Enter a number:"))`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis here:

```
 num = int(input("Enter a number:")
```

it should be:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
```